# node code to search properties of a document in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

```
var marklogic=require('marklogic');
var ins=marklogic.createDatabaseClient({'host':'localhost','port':'7010','user':'admin','password':'admin',});
var qb=marklogic.queryBuilder;
ins.documents.query(
  qb.propertiesFragment(
    qb.value("Author","Akhilesh Sabbisetti"))
  ).result(function(matches){
    matches.forEach(function(match){
      console.log(match.uri);
    });
  });
```

The above code should work only on properties of the document, but it was not working like that. I was getting irrelevant results.  Please correct my code....

Comment: Can you reproduce the case with two very small documents, and share those with us?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a [qb.where()](https://docs.marklogic.com/jsdoc/queryBuilder.html#where) method:

```
var marklogic=require('marklogic');
var ins=marklogic.createDatabaseClient({'host':'localhost','port':'7010','user':'admin','password':'admin',});
var qb=marklogic.queryBuilder;
ins.documents.query(
qb.where(
  qb.propertiesFragment(
    qb.value("Author","Akhilesh Sabbisetti"))
  )
).result(function(matches){
    matches.forEach(function(match){
      console.log(match.uri);
    });
  });
```

Also may I recommend that you use a promise resolve handling pattern in the following format and allow for catching errors as well:

```
db.documents.query(
  qb.where(
    qb.propertiesFragment(
      qb.value('Author', 'Akhilesh Sabbisetti')
    )
  )
)
.result()
.then(function(matches) {
  console.log(matches);
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```